# Tweepy Streaming proxy

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to extract data from twitter in certain area. But the code can't run, it return a ConnectionError: Failed to establish a new connection.

I can't find the error in the code. So i think it must need to configure the request. But i couldn't find solution to configure a proxy in tweepy streaming.

Although i try some method to modify the code. But there also have a error. So i am appreciated some one can give me any suggestion.

```
import sys
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy='127.0.0.1:1080')


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if 'python' in status.text.lower():
            print (status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())    
sapi.filter(locations=[-6.38,49.87,1.77,55.81])
```

this is the error i have got:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000D37F2E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] 由于连接方在一段时间后没有正确答复或连接的主机没有反应，连接尝试失败。',))
```

Comment: Has it worked before? Try instantiating a `CustomStreamListener` object (i.e.: `mystream = CustomStreamListener()`) then do `sapi = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=mystream)`

Comment: Thanks for you help. But, when i try the suggestion you have given, it doesn't work well.  It returned the same error.  It is my first time to try to extract data from twitter,  I can't find a suitable solution.

Comment: A `ConnectionError` usually has something to do with network settings, DNS, IP configuration, etc.. maybe something to do with your internet connection?

Comment: I think maybe it cause by the China's firewall configuration. So i want to try  use the proxy to solve this problem. Can you find any code error in this script? Or it can work on you computer correctly?  If so, i will try some other ways to across the firewall. For anyway, thanks for you help again.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the normal Twitter website using that proxy?